# linked in custom url scheme for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, linkedin-api, url-scheme

Anybody know the linked in custom url scheme to pass the text to the create message screen of linked in iOS App?

I know that "linkedin://share" will open up the create message screen but I need to pass the text that I want to share as well.Anybody know the parameter name for that?

Comment: Did you check if Linked-In documents their app's custom URL scheme?

Comment: I was not able to find a document that provides the details regarding that.

Answer (score 1):

```
linkedin://messaging/compose/username
```

Comment: If you add a source of above info, It would help an author to accept this as an answer.